# How would I go about storing data for specific 'user' without accounts (cookie?)?

Tags: cookies, local-storage, progressive-web-apps

Basically the idea is to make an app which stores 'times' for Rubik's Cube solves (as [qqtimer.net](https://www.qqtimer.net)). Also wanted to make it a PWA. As I'm new to web development, I'm not quite sure how to go about storing those solves since the app **wouldn't require user accounts (logging in)**. Simply open the app in the browser, use it, and it keeps the data as long as we don't clear cookies/cache(?).
I read about cookies/local storage(indexedDB?) to try and figure out how to go about it but I'm not quite sure. The idea is that the data should exist for a 'user' in a browser. Also there's no need to have the solves that I do on browser appear on the phone or vice-versa (pwa just to be able to use on phone) even though I would like to know if that's possible (maybe using google account?).

Ultimately, what I want is to know what I should use/look into (cookies, database, local storage, etc..).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used indexedDB for storing locally in the browser